# Java - How to identify whether a method executed completely or Returned

Tags: java, methods, return, execution

Is there a way to identify whether the following method executed completely or returned halfway through(i.e at line no 3)

```
static int a=0;
static void test(){
     if(a>10){
          return;
     }
     a++;
}
```

The method was invoked by another method.(a might have been changed by it)

I cannot change the method declaration. I am dealing with an object I created from a java file created by someone else. I am not allowed to change the original file

Comment: This method does nothing.

Comment: It would be better if you understand [try-catch-finally block](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html).. It helps you check whether your method executed completely or not..

Comment: Since no path the logic can take inside the method changes anything, no, there is no way.

Comment: For the edited version you could check the value of `a` before and after the method call.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking because you are not posting real code nor giving all necessary conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Your method does almost nothing and no there is no way in this example you gave to know if the method returned before complete execution but if you willing to change the function to a boolean type you can return `true` at complete execution and `false` at incomplete.

```
static boolean test()
{
  if(a>10)
     return false;
  a++;
  return true;
 }
```

Comment: I cannot change the method declaration. I am dealing with an object I created from a java file created by someone else. I am not allowed to change the original file

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda Then you simply cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Run the code under debugger like [jdb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) and set the breakpoint on the internal return statement. If the program stops at this breakpoint, this obviously means that it would return through that statement.

To make things more automated, you could try to launch the debugger and control the debugger from a Java program through Runtime. This would make the approach applicable for more use cases, while not for all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
void test(int a) {
    if (a > 10) {
        return;
    }
    a++;
    System.out.println("test executed completely!");
}
```

Or if you want to use the information programmatically

```
private boolean executedCompletely;

void test(int a) {
    executedCompletely = false;
    if (a > 10) {
        return;
    }
    a++;
    executedCompletely = true;
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the method declaration. I am dealing with an object I created from a java file created by someone else. I am not allowed to change the original file

Comment: Well you could check the value of a (if you have access to that) before and after method execution. Provided the method was only executed one single time then if the value of a changed (and provided the value of a is not changed elsewhere in the code) the method was executed completely. I have to say doing so really doesen't make much sense as it would be very bad code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your test method, you can check whether it ran completely this way:

```
int initialA = a;
test();
int finalA = a;
if (finalA != initialA) {
    //a has been changed, therefore the method ran completely
} else {
    //a has not been changed, therefore it was not incremented, therefore the method did not run completely
}
```